# UIPageViewController viewControllers always return a single controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have two view controllers inside a `UIPageViewController`. I need to get all view controllers inside the `UIPageViewController` to call methods inside them, but it always returns a single page only (either the first page or the second page).

The code is below for convenience:

```
if let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.viewControllers {

   print(viewControllers)

   for controller in viewControllers {
       if let firstController: FirstViewController = controller as? FirstViewController {
          //Call something
       }
       if let secondController: SecondViewController = controller as? SecondViewController {
           //Call something
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, it returns only the visible view controller inside the page controller.

Comment: "I have two view controllers inside UIPageViewController" No, you don't. `print(self.viewControllers.count)` will reveal the truth of the matter.

Answer (score 2):

This is intended behaviour.

In a simple `UIPageViewController`, this array will **only return the currently visible view controller(s)**, which is usually just one view controller.

Keep in mind that `UIPageViewController` **heavily caches** and **reuses** controllers, just like a `UITableViewController` would. You may want to reflect changes in another way.

Comment: You notched it, silly me; It will show multiple controllers if more than one controller visible at a single time.